# spring boot - How to load context configuration file

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am trying to convert spring mvc app to spring boot. I used to deploy this application in tomcat and test. Now with spring boot I am trying to do the same thing but I am facing issues to load xml file configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Data sources -->
    <Environment name="/source/schema" value="${schema}" type="java.lang.String" />

    <Resource auth="Container" driverClass="org.postgresql.Driver" 
            factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
            idleConnectionTestPeriod="30" jdbcUrl="${url}" 
            maxAdministrativeTaskTime="0" maxConnectionAge="30" maxIdleTime="9" maxPoolSize="3" minPoolSize="2" 
            name="/source/DataSource" password="${password}" 
            preferredTestQuery="select 1" testConnectionOnCheckout="true" type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" user="${user}"/>
</Context>
```

This is my configuration file which I am trying to load. When I put

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml", "classpath:context.xml"})
```

I am able to load all the bean configuration from applicationcontext.xml but while loading context.xml it is giving

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Context'.
```

How should I load these entries when deploying spring boot app in tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

By default, JNDI is disabled in embedded Tomcat. You need to call Tomcat.enableNaming() to enable it.

If you can live by Java config,you can try below snippet to add JNDI and other configurations from context.xml using the java config.

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}
```

Example :

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("jdbc/myDataSource");
            resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "your.db.Driver");
            resource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:yourDb");

            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
        }
    };
}

@Bean(destroyMethod="")
public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource");
    bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
    bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (DataSource)bean.getObject();
}
```

Have a look at this [github link](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi) for related sample

Comment: This setting is for embedded tomcat. I want to create a war and deploy on tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

`context.xml` should go into the `/META-INF/` directory in your war files. It is instructions to the Tomcat server, there's no need to configure anything in Spring to try to load it.